# Simple relation between angle - not so simple algebra

Tags: trigonometry

Let take the points $A=(a,0)$, $B=(b,0)$, $C=(x,y)$, all in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume that $a>b>x$ for simplicity.

The angle $\angle ACB$, which I'll call $\alpha$, is determined by the cosine law:

$\alpha = \cos^{-1}\left( \ \frac{ (\overline{BC})^2 + (\overline{AC})^2 - (\overline{AB})^2 }{ 2 (\overline{BC}) (\overline{AC}) } \ \right) \\ 
=\cos^{-1}\left( \ \frac{ [ (x-a)^2 + y^2 ] + [ (x-b)^2 + y^2 ] - [ (b-a)^2 ] }{ 2 \left[ \sqrt{ ((x-a)^2 + y^2) } \right]\left[ \sqrt{ ((x-b)^2 + y^2) } \right] } \ \right)$

At the same time, if I project the point $C$ onto the horizontal axis, I'll get a point $X=(x,0)$. Then I have two new triangles $ACX$ and $BCX$, where:

$\theta_{\angle ACX} = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{x-a}{y} \right)$

$\theta_{\angle BCX} = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{x-b}{y} \right)$

It is obvious that $ \theta_{\angle ACX} - \theta_{\angle BCX} = \alpha$ (just by drawing out the triangles, it is crystal clear). BUT I have no idea how to show this algebraically due to the presence of the $\tan^{-1}$'s and $\cos^{-1}$. Is there some trick I can use in order to show this equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula for tangent of a sum:
$$
\tan(\angle ACX) = \tan(\angle ACB + \angle BCX) = {\tan (\angle ACB) + \tan (\angle BCX) \over 1 - \tan (\angle ACB )\tan (\angle BCX)}\tag1
$$
Here $\angle ACB=\alpha$. Knowing what $\cos(\alpha)$ is, compute $\sin(\alpha)$ and therefore $\tan(\alpha)$, and plug this along with $\tan(\angle BCX)$ into (1). This will simplify to what you want. You can make your life easier by assuming without loss of generality that $x=0$.

Note if you're assume $a>b>x$, then $\tan(\angle ACX) = (a-x)/y$ and $\tan(\angle BCX)=(b-x)/y$.